# Best tool to move from Oracle to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I have a big Oracle DB: 4+ GB of data, 200 tables, 1000+ stored procedures and functions.

Does anyone recommend a tool for the DB structure and data migration?

Comment: Oracle already uses SQL.  Did you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: This is subjective, please read FAQs on more of what is a suitable question for SO.

Comment: 4GB is not 'big'. The 1000+ stored procedures will be a bigger challenge and suggests the application is very Oracle centric. If you want portability, I'd look at moving that logic into an app layer and not migrate it to SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check Microsft Documentation on [this](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#oracle).

And here is the [migration](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C7933D3E-B7B9-43A6-ADE3-F8E37C8CB046&displaylang=en) Package MS offers.

[DB Best](http://www.dbbest.com/) can also help you in migration.

And here is an [article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/migrating-from-oracle-to-sql-server/)  on Oracle to SQL Server 2000 migration.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [SQL Server Migration Assistance for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16742), by MSFT. It is real simple point and click migration utitlity with good UI.

But I think real issue will be converting PL/SQL specific code into T-SQL format, rest of migration is easy.